# iOS: JSON upload progress

Tags: ios, upload, alamofire

I need to upload a big json (containing a UIImage as base64) file to a server and would like to track progress. I tried with Alamofire, but it seems as the file is uploaded first and only the response is progress-able. I can't use multipart as the API does not support that. Is it even possible to get the upload progress when only a body-json is sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work with `upload` method and json converted to data. Used some random image and mock api for testing.

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "test")!)!
let json = ["test": imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)]
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
self.sessionManager.upload(jsonData!, to: "https://demo1752132.mockable.io/test", method: .post).responseJSON { dataResponse in

}.uploadProgress { progress in
    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I tried this already the answer to this is **NO**. I have succeeded with files progress whereas for body-json I couldn't able to track the progress.

I will try to explain my scenario which is may be similar to you. I have to upload multiple images with text on stream. For us, the API for media is different. I mean for each image I have to upload to server and get the response. In the final request, I have to send all collected urls along with text in body of json. In this scenario, I tracked all images uploading successfully and showed it well. When coming to the final request, I couldn't able to track it.

Will be happy to know If someone finds tracking it.

Comment: are you sure about this? I suspected that as well, but I'm not sure at all that it won't work